# Image array. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

First time messing with arrays. Trying to cycle through an image array, getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null" when clicking the next button. I thought it would be something simple like an id not matching up, but I can't spot any issues like that.

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');

var counter = 0;

var imageArray = [
 "megatron.png",
 "starscream.jpg",
 "soundwave.jpg",
 "shockwave.jpg",
 "devastator.jpg",
 "astrotrain.jpg",
 "blitzwing.jpg",
 "thrust.jpg",
 "rumble.png",
 "ravage.jpg",
 "laserbeak.jpg",
 "reflector.jpg"
];

function next() {
 counter = counter + 1;
 if (counter > imageArray.length -1) {
  counter = 0;
 }
 target.src = imageArray[counter];
}
```

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Image Array</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./image-array.css">
 <script src="image-array.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="center">Image Array</h1>
<div id="page" class="center">
 <div id="socket" class="center">
  <img src="megatron.png" id="target">
 </div>
 <div id="switchplate" class="center">
   <button onclick="next()" id="next">Next</button>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of the loading of `<script src="image-array.js"></script>` is in the head tag.

When the above script is loaded it will run through this statement

```
var target = document.getElementById('target');
```

At that time the DOM is not ready and there is no element with id `target`

So it is throwing the error.

Remove the script tag and add it before closing body tag

```
<body>
  // rest of the DOM
<script src="image-array.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, looks like I have some reading to do! I assumed that having the script tag in the head would always be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the working sample of your code.Please check

```js
var counter = 0;

var imageArray = [
 "https://doodles.google.ca/d4g/images/splashes/featured.png", "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/a/aa/Google_Assistant.png/revision/latest?cb=20170815132456",
 "http://st1.bgr.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/google-search.jpg"
];

function next() {
 counter = counter + 1;
 if (counter > imageArray.length -1) {
  counter = 0;
 }
 target.src = imageArray[counter];
}
```

```html
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Image Array</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./image-array.css">
<script src="image-array.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="center">Image Array</h1>
<div id="page" class="center">
 <div id="socket" class="center">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLxmBuSqBLEVe6FZkt8CK7GxewFiDHOihhgod4ncC8H0hPVV6w" style="width:100px;height:100px;" id="target" >
 </div>
 <div id="switchplate" class="center">
   <button onclick="next()" id="next">Next</button>
 </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does this work without "var target = document.getElementById('target');" ? And why does it fix it?